# Modulemap won't compile after switching to macOS Catalina - tcp_var.h

Tags: swift, tcp, macos-catalina, module-map

I am the developer of a small tool that will track the network speed. This code resides in a small framework which sues a module map, so I can use the C code in Swift.

Here is my (old) modulemap:

```
module PrivateNetwork [system]
{
    header "/usr/include/sys/socketvar.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if_dl.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if_types.h"
    header "/usr/include/net/if.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/in.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h"

    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcpip.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/tcp_fsm.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/ip.h"
    header "/usr/include/netinet/ip6.h"

    export *
}
```

After switching to macOS Catalina, the /usr/include/ folders were no longer found, so I had to change them:

```
module PrivateNetwork [system]
{
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/sys/socketvar.h"

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/ip6.h"

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp_fsm.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h" // > ip.h (in_addr), > tcp.h (tcp_seq)
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcpip.h" // > ip.h (in_addr)

    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if_types.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if.h"
    header "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/net/if_dl.h"

    export *
}
```

I already made some changes, because after adding the full path, the modulemap no longer compiles.
I get the following error:

`Declaration of 'tcp_seq' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.netinet.tcp' before it is required`

Full version:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h:120:2: Declaration of 'tcp_seq' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.netinet.tcp' before it is required`.

I don't understand this, because the header tcp.h, where the struct is defined, is imported before the tcp_var.h header.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the tcp.h header import and now it compiles.